# Crontab setting when minute ends in a specific digit

Tags: cron

Just interested in the shortened version of the following for the **minutes interval**:

```
5,15,25,35,45,55

8,18,28,38,48,58
```

I know they essentially the same, just a different ending digit.

Thanks.

Comment: Please note that what appears above is only the minutes setting...I fully realize there are other settings including, hours, days, months, year and the actual action to be taken. My focus here is merely on whether or not there us a shorter definition to the minutes digit ending in a '5'. I want to try to condense the length of my crontab instruction...that's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition in the initial question is as short as it can be made.

Comment: I'll come back after 2 days and set the answer

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
5,15,25,35,45,55 * * * * yourcommand

8,18,28,38,48,58 * * * * yourcommand
```

Comment: Ha ha...I didn't think there was a shortened method. Thanks @Hyperboreus

Answer (score 0):

Just put 8,18,28,38,48,58 etc in the 'minutes' field.

Ie:

```
8,18,28,38,48,58 * * * * /path/to/command
```

Comment: Ok...I didn't think there was a shortened method. Thanks @stefgosselin